# If $G = S_5$ and $H = \{g \in G \mid g^{5} = e\}$ how could I determine and prove whether or not $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

I think that the this group contains the 5 element cycles and the identity e but overall I'm not sure how to prove that the product of the 2 members of H is also a 5 cycle or e.

Comment: $(1\;2\;3\;4\;5)$ and $(3\;2\;1\;4\;5)$ are in $H$, but is $(1\;2\;3\;4\;5)\cdot(3\;2\;1\;4\;5)$ in $H$?

Comment: Oh I think it's (154), so I guess H is not a subgroup, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $$(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)(1\,2\,3\,5\,4)=(1\,3)(2\,4)$$

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, I see that H is not now!

Answer (score 4):

You could try Lagrange's Theorem which tells you something about the order of a subgroup. Count the elements of $H$.